# Bad authentication data when making Twitter GET request on Postman

Tags: authentication, twitter, access-token, postman

So I generated access token and access token secret on Twitter

[image]

However's every time I make a `GET` request on `Postman` I get `bad authentication data`:
[image]

I copy & paste the access token after `"Basic"` in the `Value` so I don't know why it's not working?? I would be so grateful if anyone helped!!!

PS I didn't put anything in the authorization tab on Postman. Not sure if that's relevant:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be getting GET not POST for statuses/user_timeline as per [Twitter API User Timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline)

```
GET statuses/user_timeline
```